# An -ing ending adjective that doesn't have a base verb form

Tags: adjectives

Is there such an -ing adjective in English that would not have a counterpart in the list below?:

```
interesting  -- (to) interest
amazing -- (to) amaze
disgusting -- (to) disgust
easy-going -- (to) go
winding -- (to) wind
annoying -- (to) annoy
```

Or is it like all -ing adjectives are essentially present participles, that is, forms of a verb, so there will always be a base verb-form for each one of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"**swing**" is an adjective used every day in USA news reports.

There are "*swing voters will decide the presidential election*" and "*Justice Smith is the swing Justice on the US Supreme Court for cases involving whatever*".

Comment: It's not an adjective. It's a noun used as an adjunct, so it behaves like an adjective.

Comment: @Kris I think I agree. I technically consider the "swing" in  "swing voter" to be classified as an "attributive noun". But, more generally, "attributive nouns" are adjectives because they modify nouns. And for the purpose of this question, "swing" is not a present participle.

Comment: As I noted already, attributive nouns are, of course, nouns, not adjectives; they just "behave like an adjective" (functionally, that is).

Answer (score 3):

The answer might depend on whether you mean historically/diachronically, or in terms of whether the *-ing* word is currently/synchronically felt to be based on a related verb. If you are asking whether there is always a synchronic base, the adjective **cunning** seems to work as an answer to your first question. "(To) cun" does not exist as a verb in standard English. The adjective *cunning* is derived from an obsolete present participle form of the verb *can* (which once had an infinitive form built on the stem *cunn-*), but in modern English *can* inflects as a modal auxiliary and so lacks non-finite forms. Therefore, *cunning* cannot be interpreted as a present participle of *can,* and I think it would be incorrect to argue even for a derivational synchronic connection between *can* and *cunning.*

In response to your final question, linguists generally agree that not all *-ing* words in English are forms of a verb. An *-ing* word modified by *very,* such as *exciting* in "a very exciting day", is usually classified as an adjective that is lexically separate from the verb *excite,* rather than an inflected form of it. In contrast, *exciting* in a sentence like "The teachers should be exciting the students about learning" **would** be classified as an inflected form of the verb *excite.*

Some *-ing* adjectives are compounds without a corresponding single-word verb, like your example *easy-going,* which does not correspond to a single-word verb. Another example: the adjective *everlasting* exists, but **everlast* is not in general use as a verb ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/everlast#English) records two examples that are negligible because of their rarity). *Good-looking*, which is used adjectivally, is spelled with a hyphen and could be categorized as a single, compound word, but **good-look* is not in common use as a verb: instead, the two-word phrase *look good* is used (with *look* inflected into the appropriate form, e.g. "looking good"). Parts of these words are based on a verb, but the whole word is composed of more than just a verb plus the suffix *-ing.*

Comment: +1 but is _can_ a typo of _cun_?

Comment: @JK2: Where? *Can* is used as the lemma of the present-day English verb because it has no infinitive form. *Cun* is an obsolete form. In "cunning cannot be interpreted as a present participle of can", I meant that *cunning* cannot be interpreted as a present participle of the currently existing English modal verb *can,* even though they are genuinely related from the viewpoint of etymology.

Comment: Oh, I see. Sorry I was mistaken.

Comment: Cf. "ken". There indeed is an etymological relation between *cunning* and  *can*. Research a bit. Good Luck.

Comment: Cun me once, shame on ... . Well ... cun me once, shame on me... .Gah! Ya see, you can't cun me again.